# Template class issues

Tags: c++, templates

I am having the following problem. Consider this (very simplified) example. I am using one of our existing template classes that I am able to add (up to a point) some generic functionality to:

```
template<typename T> class myClass
{
public:
    typedef T element_type;
    explicit myClass(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}           
    ~myClass() { delete ptr; };    

    ......

private:
    T* ptr;    
};
```

I am also using an external library (which I am obviously not able to adjust) which amongst other things defines (lets say) `struct notMine`.  As this is a C style library, one does some sort of `notMine* nmPtr = createNotMine();` call and I need to remember to `freeNotMine(nmPtr);` when I am done.

Now I want to use `myClass` with a pointer to a `notMine` structure but the problem is that when `myClass` goes out of scope, I 'forget' to free this `notMine` structure and it calls 'delete' instead.

What is a nice way of fixing this problem?

- Do I create class derived from myClass where I can write my own destructor specific to this problem?
- Do I adjust myClass so I can pass some sort of optional generic Destructor object?
- Do I adjust myClass so I can (optionally) pass a static function that is to be called in the destructor?

EDIT: I probably didn't explain myself properly, but the myClass is already being used elsewhere, so I cannot simply change the existing destructor to suit this particular problem

Comment: Two simple solutions: Either don't delete the pointer in the destructor (after all, it's not your pointer, you haven't allocated it, why should you free it?), or use e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) *all the way*.

Comment: Can you implement another class? Or add template parameters to  `myClass`?

Comment: yes I can add functionality as long as it is backwards compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For you immediate implementation**

Given than the class can be modified (maintaining backwards compatibility), you can extend the class to include a custom deleter to manage the resource (with a suitable default). Custom deleters can then be implemented for each type that the class needs to maintain.

```
template <typename T>
struct DefaultDeleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) const {
        delete ptr;
    }
}

struct NotMineDeleter { // or a specialisation of DefaultDeleter
    void operator()(notMine* nmPtr) const {
        if (nmPtr)
           freeNotMine(nmPtr);
    }
}

template<typename T, typename Deleter = DefaultDeleter<T> >
class myClass
{
public:
    typedef T element_type;
    explicit myClass(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}           
    ~myClass() { deleter_(ptr); };    

    ......

private:
    Deleter deleter_;
    T* ptr;    
};
```

The `myClass` can now be used as follows for the external library;

```
myClass<notMine, NotMineDeleter> obj(createNotMine());
```

You will also need to deal with the copy and assignments for your class `myClass` by either making them `private:` (C++03), deleting them `=delete;` (C++11) or implementing the appropriately, i.e. implement the full copy and assignment semantics.

You've commented that the copy and assignments are implemented appropriately (this will need to be the case for the `notMine*` pointers as well). If this is not the case, then you will probably run into further problems.

C++11 also brings with it move semantics that can be implemented to transfer ownership from one instance of `myClass` to another.

**Better yet**

Use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::share_ptr` with a custom deleter that calls `freeNotMine(nmPtr)`.

RAII - what it looks like you are doing is implementing a classic RAII class. This is a very good thing and one of the core idiomatic uses of resource classes in C++.

**Alternative to the dual deleter above**

Using template specialisation, the implementation can be simplified (but essentially still maintains deleters for each type being maintained) as follows;

```
template <typename T>
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) const {
        delete ptr;
    }
}

template <>
struct Deleter<notMine> {
    void operator()(notMine* nmPtr) const {
        if (nmPtr)
           freeNotMine(nmPtr);
    }
}

template<typename T>
class myClass
{
public:
    typedef T element_type;
    explicit myClass(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}           
    ~myClass() { deleter_(ptr); };    

    ......

private:
    Deleter<T> deleter_;
    T* ptr;    
};
```

The `myClass` can now be used as follows for the external library;

```
myClass<notMine> obj(createNotMine());
```

Comment: Niall, thanks for the response - I edited my original post as I didn't make it clear that myClass is already being used elsewhere. And the copy & assignments are taken care of already - I just didn't write them in this (simplified) example ..

Comment: Niall, thanks so much for your suggestion. I had actually come across this idea when I was looking at a shared_ptr implementation which does something similar (but I didn't quite understand).

Comment: @Lieuwe, It's a pleasure, in all the implementation the key is to understand the "routing" of the resource to the appropriate deleter when the object goes out of scope.